# How do I get the month one calendar month ago in bash?

Tags: bash, date

I have been using the command:

```
date --date='1 months ago' +%b
```

To get the month name of the month it was a month ago, but have realised today as it is the 31st that this command actually gives me the month name it was 4 weeks ago.

Is there any way to get the calendar month that it was 1 month ago, or indeed n months ago as I can see that the discrepancy will be greater as the number of months is longer.

Comment: It actually gives you 1st July, so 30 days ago

Comment: You can find the answer here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168463/using-date-command-to-get-previous-current-and-next-month

Comment: It's because there's no 31st June. This is explained well in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Date calculations that depend on the number of days in the month are tricky. A hybrid approach, using month numbers and a lookup table, will probably work best.

```
months=("" Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
echo ${months[$(date +%m) - 1 ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ $(date +%d) == "31" ]] && date -d'-31 day' +%b || date -d'-1 month' +%b
```

test with today:

```
kent$ date
Thu Jul 31 17:34:27 CEST 2014

kent$ [[ $(date +%d) == "31" ]] && date -d'-31 day' +%b || date -d'-1 month' +%b
Jun
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one line

```
#if the month before 30 days is the same of the actual month ,then return the month before 31 days

[[ `date --date='30 day ago' +%b` == `date +%b` ]] && echo `date --date='31 day ago' +%b` || echo `date --date='30 day ago' +%b`
```